# mbstring.so and curl.so can't be loaded by PHP under Ubuntu

Tags: php

I download PHP source code to build and install it.

But **mbstring.so** and **curl.so** can not be loaded by PHP.

1. I've remove ; from php.ini
2. **mbstring.so** and **curl.so** exist in extension folder
3. other extension files can be loaded. I've tested with **gd.so**. I remove ; before gd.so, it can be see in phpinfo, I add ;, gd.so is hidden in phpinfo.

Anybody know why?

PHP version is **5.4.13**.

Comment: Do these files actually present in source and match PHP version? Are they readable?

Comment: Actually, I build these extensions by source code too. So the version is matched. And all of extensions have the same privilege.

Comment: It seems some problem with Apache. I copy some mod files from /usr/lib/apache2/moduels to /usr/local/apache2/moduels, then **mbstring.so** is loaded now!  But curl.so is still missing.